# "Error installing GRUB" during Ubuntu Installation

Tags: ubuntu, grub, format

I was trying to do something with `dd` command in Ubuntu's terminal. But I screwed up. I don't really remember what the command was.

But after I ran it, I restarted the PC and I read a message "No operating system found".

So as I wanted to install the new Ubuntu, 11.04, I just picked up a bootable pen drive with that OS and tried to install it. I wanted to completely clean the hard drive and make a fresh install. How ever when I try to do this, in the middle of the installation an error message pops up and it says that there was an **error installing GRUB**.

I don't have anything else in the hard drive, no particions and only one disc. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a rescue CD like [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) and clean the disk with `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024000
```

Use `/dev/hda` for older systems. After this initialize the partition table with `fdisk`. After that try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I am going to try that and tell the results in here. Thank you!

Comment: It worked without problems. Thank you very must!